# Does state dependent probability density lead to time dependent inner product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, probability

I have recently come across the following statement in my study:

*If the probability density on a Hilbert space is dependent upon the states, then the inner product is time dependent.*

Is there any intuitive way (or better still, an explicit way) to understand or prove this?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a source for your quote? I am struggling to understand what it is trying to say without more context.

Comment: It's just what my teacher stated in class. I feel stumped too. It was in the course of discussing time-independence of inner products and how exactly they induce a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Razor Not sure about the context of the statement in your question either, but a word of caution on " time-independence of inner products and how exactly they induce a Hilbert space":  The time-independence of inner products is a matter of unitary dynamics, while the Hilbert space is a space of pure states, and is independent of the particular dynamics. In fact a well-defined linear dynamics, such as a quantum channel, is generally not unitary.